# The connection either timed out or was lost- Error while cube synchronization from source server to destination

Tags: ssas, cube, msbi

I am executing XMLA script via scheduled SSIS dtsx package to synchronize the ssas cube form source to destination server. Everytime it works fine but sometimes it gives error in random manner like once in 2-3 months. Error is : "The connection either timed out or was lost"

Later when I perform synchronization manually it works. I checked from network between 2 server, configuration , data related settings and also from memory perspective, but everything seems fine.

Can you please guide how to tackle this?